# Dynamic Multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need a multidimensional array of chars that is dynamic in only one dimension...
I have to store a pair of strings with a length of 10 (or less) chars each, but with a variable number of "pairs".

My idea was this

```
char (*instrucao)[2][10];
```

Which gives me a pointer to a 2x10 array of chars, but this is not working properly when i do something like this:

```
char strInstrucoes[117], *conjunto = calloc(21, sizeof(char));
instrucao = calloc(1, sizeof(char[2][10]));
conjunto = strtok(strInstrucoes,"() ");
for(i = 0; conjunto != NULL; i++){
    realloc(instrucao, i+1*sizeof(char[2][10]));
    sscanf(conjunto,"%[^,],%s", instrucao[i][0], instrucao[i][1]);
    printf("%s | %s\n", instrucao[i][0], instrucao[i][1]);
    conjunto = strtok(NULL, "() ");
}
```

Having `strInstrucoes` as `(abc,123) (def,456) (ghi,789)`, I don't matrix with 3 lines of 2 pairs each like this:

```
abc | 123
def | 456
ghi | 789
```

but instead this is what I'm getting:

```
abc | 123
def | 45def | 45de
ghi | 789
```

What's the right way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign the pointer the new address `realloc` returns

```
instrucao = realloc(instrucao, (i+1)*sizeof(char[2][10]));
```

Note that for error checking, you may desire to assign to a new pointer and check for `NULL`. Also note the parens - you basically just added `i` instead of multiplying with the required size. Easily overseen.

Note that there is no need for the initial `calloc`. Just initialize `instrucao` to `NULL`, and realloc will behave like `malloc` when first passed a null pointer.

Comment: Absolutely right... And looking throughmy old codes, i noticed I never actually assigned the pointer to realloc. Good thing I don't work with C professionally, then! Thanks very much

Comment: Realloc is designed so it can return the same address you gave to it, so it doesn't have to realloc but just enlarge the region it allows to be accessed. But sometimes, real reallocation happens, too. Also note that you should probably limit the characters read. like  sscanf(conjunto, "%9[^,],%9s", ...); otherwise evil dudes could cause buffer overflows.

Comment: @litb Yeah, but in this case I have absolute control over the input data (i'm writing all the files), so I didn't worry much about it

Answer (score 0):

You would do much better to find a library with a container that will meet your needs.  At the very worst, using none of the much better libraries, you could have two separate arrays, each of them holding half of the pair.